# TS server to SBS 2003 server - CAL

Tags: terminal-server, windows-sbs-2003, cal

If I connect to TS over RDP and after that run application which resides on SBS 2003 server (shared app directory), do I need to buy SBS 2003 CAL beside TS CAL?

Comment: With Windows Server 2003 being EOL can you actually still buy legitimate CAL's?

Comment: I'm not sure... but I think you can buy SBS 2011 CALs and then exercise downgrade rights.